# Make a pixmap transparent for a QLabel

Tags: qt, transparency, qpixmap

I have a MainWindow with a QLabel and a pixmap. I want to make it transparent (or less opaque)

I am using the following code below.

```
ui->label->setAttribute(Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground);
ui->label->repaint();
```

However it does not seem to work. The image looks the same without any changes. I also tried to use to the following statement:

```
    ui->label->setStyleSheet("background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 10);");
```

Unfortunately, this does not seem to work either.

Anyone knows how can I make an image transparent or make it less opaque?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Are you sure that your image is transparent? Did you try `background-color: transparent;`?

Comment: Could you provide simple program, that reproduce your problem? Because labels with images are transparent in my test app.

Comment: @DmitrySazonov I think he wants to adjust the transparency of the image, not the `QLabel` itself.

Comment: @thuga then he should use `QGraphicsOpacityEffect`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If your image isn't transparent as it is and you want it to be, you can do something like this:

```
QLabel *l = new QLabel(this);
QImage image(":/img/myimage.png");
QPainter p;
p.begin(&image);
p.setCompositionMode(QPainter::CompositionMode_DestinationIn);
p.fillRect(image.rect(), QColor(0, 0, 0, 50));
p.end();
l->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(image));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use method `fill`, example:

```
pixmap = QPixmap(width_size_in_pixels, height_size_in_pixels)
pixmap.fill(Qt.transparent)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can apply [QGraphicsOpacityEffect](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qgraphicsopacityeffect.html) to a label to adjust it's opacity.